# Find executable files having no extensions?

Tags: linux, bash, find

Following program list me all files in a directory but how can I display only those 'executable' files having no extension ?

```
find $workingDir/testcases -type f -perm -og+rx  | while read file
do
        echo $file  
done
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use:

```
find $workingDir/testcases -type f ! -name "*.*" -perm -og+rx
```

Comment: what does `!` do? i didn't know about its existence

Comment: ! or -not will invert the match

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

DIR="./";

find $DIR -type f -perm -og+rx  | while read file
do
    echo $file | egrep -v "\.[^/]+$";
done
```